# New line in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Doing print_r on my array produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => dogs
    [1] => cats

    [2] => birds
)
```

The newline between cats and birds is causing a problem. I did the following and the spacing still persists: `array_walk($arr,'trim');`

What can be done to remove this spacing?

Comment: How are the entries being populated?

Comment: how you populate the array?

Comment: Can you `var_export($yourarray);` and post it here ?

Comment: Most probably you have forgotten a new line in the `cats` entry.

Comment: The final array element is populated by $arr[] = "birds"

Comment: `array_walk` returns a boolean , so the way u are doing it is wrong.

Comment: You can try str_replace("\n", '', $arr);

Comment: is it a new line or an html break, I mean is this an html preview of output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`array_walk`](http://www.php.net/array_walk) returns a boolean. Use [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/array_map) instead:

```
$arr = array_map("trim", $arr);
```

Answer (score 8):

`array_walk` won't help you, since it does not by itself persist any changes to the data. Use `array_map` instead:

```
$arr = array_map('trim', $arr);
```

If possible you should eliminate that extraneous line break from the beginning though, not filter it out after the fact.